# Comment analyser « jusque + de » ?

Tags: sens, syntaxe

<sub>Source: p 599. *L'être et le néant* (original de 1943; éd Gallimard de 1976) par J-P Sartre.</sub>

> N'est-ce pas moi qui décide du coefficient d'adversité des
>   choses et
>   jusque **de** leur imprévisibilité en décidant de moi-même ?
>
> [ [jusque :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jusque) ] 1. Marque un certain terme `au-delà duquel on ne passe pas`. — Note : Elle est le plus souvent combinée avec la préposition à.

Je ne comprends pas l'usage de 'jusque' ici.
1. Quel syntagme (i.e. 'Phrase') ici est celui `au-delà duquel on ne passe pas` ?

2. Quel est le 'Constituent' auquel  **de** appartient ? Quelle est la décomposition correcte ?
3. N'est-ce pas moi qui [décide]<sub>VP</sub>  [...]  [jusque]<sub>PP</sub>  [**de** leur imprévisibilité]<sub>PP</sub>  [...] ?
4. N'est-ce pas moi qui [décide]<sub>VP</sub>  [...]  [jusque **de**] <sub>PP</sub>  [leur imprévisibilité]<sub>NP</sub>  [...] ?
5. N'est-ce pas moi qui [décide]<sub>VP1</sub>  [...]  [jusque]<sub>PP</sub>  [**de**]<sub>VP1</sub>  [leur imprévisibilité]<sub>NP</sub>  [...] ?

Answer (score 2):

Dans cette phrase, *jusque* est utilisé comme un synonyme de *même*, c'est-à-dire avec un sens un peu différent de l'indication d'une simple limite — il s'agit en effet de mettre l'accent sur cette limite et de souligner qu'on peut l'atteindre.

Pour cet exemple,

> N'est-ce pas moi qui décide du coefficient d'adversité des choses et jusque de leur imprévisibilité en décidant de moi-même ?

Le passage sous-entend que "décider de l'imprévisibilité des choses" est un pouvoir encore plus fort que celui de "décider du coefficient d'adversité des choses", et met en avant que "décider de soi-même" permet d'accomplir les deux. (Ce qu'on entend par ces termes m'échappe.)

Voici quelques autres exemples de constructions similaires :

> Nous avons cherché dans toute la maison et jusque dans le grenier. [Nous avons même été chercher dans le grenier.]
>
> Le patron n'a rien délégué. Il a décidé de tous les détails et jusque du papier à utiliser pour les cartons d'invitation. [Il a même décidé de quel papier on devait utiliser pour les invitations.]

Voir d'autres exemples fournis dans http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jusque à la section I.B.3.b.

Answer (score 1):

Le "de" provient ici de **décider + de**.

Le jusque se rapporte à l'action de décider, insistant sur le fait que l'imprévisibilité est à la limite du "décidable".

Bref, je vote pour la décomposition de la ligne numérotée 3.